# How to Change gulpfile.babel.js to Add HTML Locations when Running Build?

Tags: javascript, gulp, angular-fullstack, isparta

Below is the original gulpfile that came when running the generator-angular-fullstack (basically - I removed a task from running in development).

I have HTML files in 'client/components/modal/templates/' that are not getting added to the project when I run `gulp build`, so when I try serving the built code, I got an error saying:

> "Failed to load template: ./components/modal/templates/event.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)"

Can someone tell me what to change so the files in this location are brought into the project?

```js
// Generated on 2016-06-21 using generator-angular-fullstack 3.7.6
'use strict';

import _ from 'lodash';
import del from 'del';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import grunt from 'grunt';
import path from 'path';
import gulpLoadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
import http from 'http';
import open from 'open';
import lazypipe from 'lazypipe';
import {stream as wiredep} from 'wiredep';
import nodemon from 'nodemon';
import {Server as KarmaServer} from 'karma';
import runSequence from 'run-sequence';
import {protractor, webdriver_update} from 'gulp-protractor';
import {Instrumenter} from 'isparta';

var plugins = gulpLoadPlugins();
var config;

const clientPath = require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client';
const serverPath = 'server';
const paths = {
    client: {
        assets: `${clientPath}/assets/**/*`,
        images: `${clientPath}/assets/images/**/*`,
        scripts: [
            `${clientPath}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts`,
            `!${clientPath}/bower_components/**/*`,
            `!${clientPath}/{typings,test_typings}/**/*`
        ],
        styles: [`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.less`],
        mainStyle: `${clientPath}/app/app.less`,
        views: `${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.html`,
        mainView: `${clientPath}/index.html`,
        test: [`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.{spec,mock}.ts`],
        e2e: ['e2e/**/*.spec.js'],
        bower: `${clientPath}/bower_components/`
    },
    server: {
        scripts: [
          `${serverPath}/**/!(*.spec|*.integration).js`,
          `!${serverPath}/config/local.env.sample.js`
        ],
        json: [`${serverPath}/**/*.json`],
        test: {
          integration: [`${serverPath}/**/*.integration.js`, 'mocha.global.js'],
          unit: [`${serverPath}/**/*.spec.js`, 'mocha.global.js']
        }
    },
    karma: 'karma.conf.js',
    dist: 'dist'
};

/********************
 * Helper functions
 ********************/

function onServerLog(log) {
    console.log(plugins.util.colors.white('[') +
        plugins.util.colors.yellow('nodemon') +
        plugins.util.colors.white('] ') +
        log.message);
}

function checkAppReady(cb) {
    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: config.port
    };
    http
        .get(options, () => cb(true))
        .on('error', () => cb(false));
}

// Call page until first success
function whenServerReady(cb) {
    var serverReady = false;
    var appReadyInterval = setInterval(() =>
        checkAppReady((ready) => {
            if (!ready || serverReady) {
                return;
            }
            clearInterval(appReadyInterval);
            serverReady = true;
            cb();
        }),
        100);
}

function sortModulesFirst(a, b) {
    var module = /\.module\.ts$/;
    var aMod = module.test(a.path);
    var bMod = module.test(b.path);
    // inject *.module.js first
    if (aMod === bMod) {
        // either both modules or both non-modules, so just sort normally
        if (a.path < b.path) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (a.path > b.path) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (aMod ? -1 : 1);
    }
}

/********************
 * Reusable pipelines
 ********************/

let lintClientScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.tslint, require(`./${clientPath}/tslint.json`))
    .pipe(plugins.tslint.report, 'verbose');

let lintServerScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.jshint, `${serverPath}/.jshintrc`)
    .pipe(plugins.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

let lintServerTestScripts = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.jshint, `${serverPath}/.jshintrc-spec`)
    .pipe(plugins.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

let styles = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(plugins.less)

    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer, {browsers: ['last 1 version']})
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write, '.');

let transpileServer = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init)
    .pipe(plugins.babel, {
        plugins: [
            'transform-class-properties',
            'transform-runtime'
        ]
    })
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write, '.');

let mocha = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.mocha, {
        reporter: 'spec',
        timeout: 5000,
        require: [
            './mocha.conf'
        ]
    });

let istanbul = lazypipe()
    .pipe(plugins.istanbul.writeReports)
    .pipe(plugins.istanbulEnforcer, {
        thresholds: {
            global: {
                lines: 80,
                statements: 80,
                branches: 80,
                functions: 80
            }
        },
        coverageDirectory: './coverage',
        rootDirectory : ''
    });

/********************
 * Env
 ********************/

gulp.task('env:all', () => {
    let localConfig;
    try {
        localConfig = require(`./${serverPath}/config/local.env`);
    } catch (e) {
        localConfig = {};
    }
    plugins.env({
        vars: localConfig
    });
});
gulp.task('env:test', () => {
    plugins.env({
        vars: {NODE_ENV: 'test'}
    });
});
gulp.task('env:prod', () => {
    plugins.env({
        vars: {NODE_ENV: 'production'}
    });
});

/********************
 * Tasks
 ********************/

gulp.task('inject', cb => {
    runSequence(['inject:js', 'inject:css', 'inject:less', 'inject:tsconfig'], cb);
});

gulp.task('inject:js', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(plugins.inject(
            gulp.src(_.union(paths.client.scripts, ['client/app/app.constant.js', `!${clientPath}/**/*.{spec,mock}.ts`, `!${clientPath}/app/app.ts`]), {read: false})
                .pipe(plugins.sort(sortModulesFirst)),
            {
                starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
                endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->',
                transform: (filepath) => '<script src="' + filepath.replace(`/${clientPath}/`, '').replace('.ts', '.js') + '"></script>'
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(clientPath));
});

function injectTsConfig(filesGlob, tsconfigPath){
    let src = gulp.src(filesGlob, {read: false})
        .pipe(plugins.sort());

    return gulp.src(tsconfigPath)
        .pipe(plugins.inject(src, {
            starttag: '"files": [',
            endtag: ']',
            transform: (filepath, file, i, length) => {
                return `"${filepath.substr(1)}"${i + 1 < length ? ',' : ''}`;
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
}

gulp.task('inject:tsconfig', () => {
    return injectTsConfig([
        `${clientPath}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts`,
        `!${clientPath}/bower_components/**/*`,
        `typings/main.d.ts`
    ], 
    './tsconfig.client.json');
});

gulp.task('inject:tsconfigTest', () => {
    return injectTsConfig([
        `${clientPath}/**/+(*.spec|*.mock).ts`,
        `!${clientPath}/bower_components/**/*`,
        `typings/main.d.ts`
    ], 
    './tsconfig.client.test.json');
});

gulp.task('inject:css', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(plugins.inject(
            gulp.src(`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.css`, {read: false})
                .pipe(plugins.sort()),
            {
                starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
                endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->',
                transform: (filepath) => '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filepath.replace(`/${clientPath}/`, '').replace('/.tmp/', '') + '">'
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(clientPath));
});

gulp.task('inject:less', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainStyle)
        .pipe(plugins.inject(
            gulp.src(_.union(paths.client.styles, ['!' + paths.client.mainStyle]), {read: false})
                .pipe(plugins.sort()),
            {
                transform: (filepath) => {
                    let newPath = filepath
                        .replace(`/${clientPath}/app/`, '')
                        .replace(`/${clientPath}/components/`, '../components/')
                        .replace(/_(.*).less/, (match, p1, offset, string) => p1)
                        .replace('.less', '');
                    return `@import '${newPath}';`;
                }
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${clientPath}/app`));
});

// Install DefinitelyTyped TypeScript definition files
gulp.task('typings', () => {
    return gulp.src("./typings.json")
        .pipe(plugins.typings());
});

gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainStyle)
        .pipe(styles())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/app'));
});

gulp.task('copy:constant', ['constant'], () => {
    return gulp.src(`${clientPath}/app/app.constant.js`, { dot: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/app'));
})

gulp.task('transpile:client', ['typings', 'copy:constant'], () => {
    return gulp.src(['client/{app,components}/**/!(*.spec|*.mock).ts', 'typings/main.d.ts'])
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(plugins.typescript()).js
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));
});

gulp.task('transpile:client:test', ['typings'], () => {
    return gulp.src(['client/{app,components}/**/+(*.spec|*.mock).ts', 'typings/main.d.ts'])
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(plugins.typescript()).js
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/test'));
});

gulp.task('transpile:server', () => {
    return gulp.src(_.union(paths.server.scripts, paths.server.json))
        .pipe(transpileServer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${serverPath}`));
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts', cb => runSequence(['lint:scripts:client', 'lint:scripts:server'], cb));

gulp.task('lint:scripts:client', () => {
    return gulp.src(_.union(
        paths.client.scripts,
        _.map(paths.client.test, blob => '!' + blob),
        [`!${clientPath}/app/app.constant.ts`]
    ))
        .pipe(lintClientScripts());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts:server', () => {
    return gulp.src(_.union(paths.server.scripts, _.map(paths.server.test, blob => '!' + blob)))
        .pipe(lintServerScripts());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts:clientTest', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.test)
        .pipe(lintClientScripts());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts:serverTest', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test)
        .pipe(lintServerTestScripts());
});

gulp.task('jscs', () => {
  return gulp.src(_.union(paths.client.scripts, paths.server.scripts))
      .pipe(plugins.jscs())
      .pipe(plugins.jscs.reporter());
});

gulp.task('clean:tmp', () => del(['.tmp/**/*'], {dot: true}));

gulp.task('start:client', cb => {
    whenServerReady(() => {
        open('http://localhost:' + config.port);
        cb();
    });
});

gulp.task('start:server', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    config = require(`./${serverPath}/config/environment`);
    nodemon(`-w ${serverPath} ${serverPath}`)
        .on('log', onServerLog);
});

gulp.task('start:server:prod', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
    config = require(`./${paths.dist}/${serverPath}/config/environment`);
    nodemon(`-w ${paths.dist}/${serverPath} ${paths.dist}/${serverPath}`)
        .on('log', onServerLog);
});

gulp.task('start:inspector', () => {
    gulp.src([])
        .pipe(plugins.nodeInspector());
});

gulp.task('start:server:debug', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
        config = require(`./${serverPath}/config/environment`);
    nodemon(`-w ${serverPath} --debug-brk ${serverPath}`)
        .on('log', onServerLog);
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    var testFiles = _.union(paths.client.test, paths.server.test.unit, paths.server.test.integration);

    plugins.livereload.listen();

    plugins.watch(paths.client.styles, () => {  //['inject:less']
        gulp.src(paths.client.mainStyle)
            .pipe(plugins.plumber())
            .pipe(styles())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/app'))
            .pipe(plugins.livereload());
    });

    plugins.watch(paths.client.views)
        .pipe(plugins.plumber())
        .pipe(plugins.livereload());

    gulp.watch(paths.client.scripts, ['transpile:client']);// gulp.watch(paths.client.scripts, ['lint:scripts:client', 'transpile:client']);

    plugins.watch(_.union(paths.server.scripts, testFiles))
        .pipe(plugins.plumber())
        .pipe(lintServerScripts())
        .pipe(plugins.livereload());

    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep:client']);
});

gulp.task('serve', cb => {
    runSequence(['clean:tmp', 'constant', 'env:all', 'typings'],
        ['inject'],// ['lint:scripts', 'inject'],
        ['wiredep:client'],
        ['transpile:client', 'styles'],
        ['start:server', 'start:client'],
        'watch',
        cb);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', cb => {
    runSequence(
        'build',
        'env:all',
        'env:prod',
        ['start:server:prod', 'start:client'],
        cb);
});

gulp.task('serve:debug', cb => {
    runSequence(['clean:tmp', 'constant', 'typings'],
        ['lint:scripts', 'inject'],
        ['wiredep:client'],
        ['transpile:client', 'styles'],
        'start:inspector',
        ['start:server:debug', 'start:client'],
        'watch',
        cb);
});

gulp.task('test', cb => {
    return runSequence('test:server', 'test:client', cb);
});

gulp.task('test:server', cb => {
    runSequence(
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'mocha:unit',
        'mocha:integration',
        'mocha:coverage',
        cb);
});

gulp.task('mocha:unit', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.unit)
        .pipe(mocha());
});

gulp.task('mocha:integration', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.integration)
        .pipe(mocha());
});

gulp.task('test:client', ['wiredep:test', 'constant', 'transpile:client', 'transpile:client:test'], (done) => {
    new KarmaServer({
      configFile: `${__dirname}/${paths.karma}`,
      singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('wiredep:client', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /bootstrap.js/,
                '/json3/',
                '/es5-shim/',
                /font-awesome\.css/,
                /bootstrap\.css/
            ],
            ignorePath: clientPath
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${clientPath}/`));
});

gulp.task('wiredep:test', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.karma)
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /bootstrap.js/,
                '/json3/',
                '/es5-shim/',
                /font-awesome\.css/,
                /bootstrap\.css/
            ],
            devDependencies: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

/********************
 * Build
 ********************/

//FIXME: looks like font-awesome isn't getting loaded
gulp.task('build', cb => {
    runSequence(
        [
            'clean:dist',
            'clean:tmp'
        ],
        'inject',
        'wiredep:client',
        'typings',
        [
            'transpile:client',
            'transpile:server'
        ],
        [
            'build:images',
            'copy:extras',
            'copy:fonts',
            'copy:assets',
            'copy:server',
            'build:client'
        ],
        cb);
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', () => del([`${paths.dist}/!(.git*|.openshift|Procfile)**`], {dot: true}));

gulp.task('build:client', ['styles', 'html', 'constant', 'build:images'], () => {
    var manifest = gulp.src(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets/rev-manifest.json`);

    var appFilter = plugins.filter('**/app.js', {restore: true});
    var jsFilter = plugins.filter('**/*.js', {restore: true});
    var cssFilter = plugins.filter('**/*.css', {restore: true});
    var htmlBlock = plugins.filter(['**/*.!(html)'], {restore: true});

    return gulp.src(paths.client.mainView)
        .pipe(plugins.useref())
            .pipe(appFilter)
                .pipe(plugins.addSrc.append('.tmp/templates.js'))
                .pipe(plugins.concat('app/app.js'))
            .pipe(appFilter.restore)
            .pipe(jsFilter)
                .pipe(plugins.ngAnnotate())
                .pipe(plugins.uglify())
            .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
            .pipe(cssFilter)
                .pipe(plugins.cleanCss({
                    processImportFrom: ['!fonts.googleapis.com']
                }))
            .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
            .pipe(htmlBlock)
                .pipe(plugins.rev())
            .pipe(htmlBlock.restore)
        .pipe(plugins.revReplace({manifest}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}`));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    return gulp.src(`${clientPath}/{app,components}/**/*.html`)
        .pipe(plugins.angularTemplatecache({
            module: 'intranetApp'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp'));
});

gulp.task('constant', function() {
  let sharedConfig = require(`./${serverPath}/config/environment/shared`);
  return plugins.ngConstant({
    name: 'intranetApp.constants',
    deps: [],
    wrap: true,
    stream: true,
    constants: { appConfig: sharedConfig }
  })
    .pipe(plugins.rename({
      basename: 'app.constant'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${clientPath}/app/`))
});

gulp.task('build:images', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.client.images)
        .pipe(plugins.imagemin({
            optimizationLevel: 5,
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets/images`))
        .pipe(plugins.rev.manifest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets/rev-manifest.json`, {
            base: `${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets`,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets`));
});

gulp.task('copy:extras', () => {
    return gulp.src([
        `${clientPath}/favicon.ico`,
        `${clientPath}/robots.txt`,
        `${clientPath}/.htaccess`
    ], { dot: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}`));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts', () => {
    return gulp.src(`${clientPath}/bower_components/{bootstrap,font-awesome}/fonts/**/*`, { dot: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/bower_components`));
});

gulp.task('copy:assets', () => {
    return gulp.src([paths.client.assets, '!' + paths.client.images])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.dist}/${clientPath}/assets`));
});

gulp.task('copy:server', () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'package.json',
        'bower.json',
        '.bowerrc'
    ], {cwdbase: true})
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('coverage:pre', () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.server.scripts)
    // Covering files
    .pipe(plugins.istanbul({
        instrumenter: Instrumenter, // Use the isparta instrumenter (code coverage for ES6)
        includeUntested: true
    }))
    // Force `require` to return covered files
    .pipe(plugins.istanbul.hookRequire());
});

gulp.task('coverage:unit', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.unit)
        .pipe(mocha())
        .pipe(istanbul())
        // Creating the reports after tests ran
});

gulp.task('coverage:integration', () => {
    return gulp.src(paths.server.test.integration)
        .pipe(mocha())
        .pipe(istanbul())
        // Creating the reports after tests ran
});

gulp.task('mocha:coverage', cb => {
  runSequence('coverage:pre',
              'env:all',
              'env:test',
              'coverage:unit',
              'coverage:integration',
              cb);
});

// Downloads the selenium webdriver
gulp.task('webdriver_update', webdriver_update);

gulp.task('test:e2e', ['env:all', 'env:test', 'start:server', 'webdriver_update'], cb => {
    gulp.src(paths.client.e2e)
        .pipe(protractor({
            configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
        })).on('error', err => {
            console.log(err)
        }).on('end', () => {
            process.exit();
        });
});

/********************
 * Grunt ported tasks
 ********************/

grunt.initConfig({
    buildcontrol: {
        options: {
            dir: paths.dist,
            commit: true,
            push: true,
            connectCommits: false,
            message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
        },
        heroku: {
            options: {
                remote: 'heroku',
                branch: 'master'
            }
        },
        openshift: {
            options: {
                remote: 'openshift',
                branch: 'master'
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-build-control');

gulp.task('buildcontrol:heroku', function(done) {
    grunt.tasks(
        ['buildcontrol:heroku'],    //you can add more grunt tasks in this array
        {gruntfile: false}, //don't look for a Gruntfile - there is none. :-)
        function() {done();}
    );
});
gulp.task('buildcontrol:openshift', function(done) {
    grunt.tasks(
        ['buildcontrol:openshift'],    //you can add more grunt tasks in this array
        {gruntfile: false}, //don't look for a Gruntfile - there is none. :-)
        function() {done();}
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles on the same issue... the gulpfile actually does find files in places that aren't really standard (like inside subfolders of places where they'd normally be at). My problem was that I specified the dot (.) in the beginning. When I changed the paths to `components/modal/someFolder/someFile.html` it worked fine. The relative path I initially had gets messed up in production.